# Do not execute events in EDGE new version MicrosoftWebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

After the upgrade, Edge and webDriver stopped working when the dropdown item was closed.
Example: Open the drop-down list. Click on the close-button. Drop-down list is closed.
We point to any element on the page, events do not work, except mouseOver (mouseleave, mousedown),
I have found the event is stuck in the drop-down list.
The problem of source code was excluded.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Example code:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('link_pseudo_yes')
elem[1].click()
chains = ActionChains(driver)
close = driver.find_element_by_class_name("inline-stocks__popup-close")
close.click()
elem2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news__tab-text")
chains.move_to_element(elem2[1]).perform()
```

Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363
MicrosoftWebDriver 10.0.18362.1

Comment: About the upgrade, can you explain more detail about it, do you mean upgrade Edge browser or Edge web driver? Please make sure they are matched, you could check it from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), if using the legacy version Edge, we should install the edge driver using this command:`DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0`.

Comment: Besides, can you post the Enough code (about the DropDownlist and the related event) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it might be easier to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Updated windows system and EDGE browser. Installed webDriver for legacy Edge as written in the documentation

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you post the Enough code (about the DropDownlist and the related event) to reproduce the problem? Because, just according to the VBA script, it is hard to reproduce the problem. Besides, you could try to use the [execute_script()](https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu) method to execute the JavaScript script and click the button.